algorithm2e can't deal with 2 for loops? Nothing visible
I wrote this algorithm in algorithm2e and it only gets visible in the PDF when I delete the last for loop, does anyone know why?
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{variable normalization}
\KwData{CNF formula $f \in \mathbb{F}$}
\KwData{color normal form $n$, the newest literal transformation result}
\KwResult{color function $c \in \mathbb{V}_f \to \mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0$}
\ForEach{$cl \in f$ and the corresponding $ncl \in n$}{
    sort $ncl$\;
    $h \gets md5(ncl)$\;
    \ForEach{$s,v \in cl$}{
        \tcp{+= uses my special sum as described in \ref{label-compression}}
        \eIf{s}{
            $c(v)$.second += $h$\;
        }{
            $c(v)$.second += $h$\;
        }
    }
}
\ForEach{$v \in \mathbb{V}_f$}{
    \If{$c(v)$ is not sorted}{
        flip $c(v)$\;
    }
}
\end{algorithm}

This is the whole code:
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{olplainarticle}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\title{CNF Normal Form Approximation to Detect Isomorphic Duplicates}

\author[1]{Timon Paßlick}
\affil[1]{Karlsruhe Institute of Technology, Germany}

\keywords{CNF, isomorphism, normal form, approximation}

\begin{abstract}
% Please provide an abstract of no more than 300 words. Your abstract should explain the main contributions of your article, and should not contain any material that is not included in the main text.
In GBD \citep{gbd}, an isohash value is computed to overestimate isomorphic SAT instances in the database. My task for this Bachelor's thesis was to reduce the amount of false positives. I do it by ordering the variables by an isomorphic characteristic and sorting the clauses by variable ranks.
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Definitions}

\begin{align}
\text{The set of variables is }\mathbb{V} \coloneqq &\mathbb{N}^+.\\
\text{The set of literals is }\mathbb{L} \coloneqq &\mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{V}.\text{ }\bot\text{ means negation.}\\
\text{The set of CNF clauses is }\mathbb{C} \coloneqq &\{c \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{L}) \mid \mathopen|c\mathclose| < \infty \}.\\
\text{The set of CNF formulas is }\mathbb{F} \coloneqq &\{f \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C}) \mid \mathopen|f\mathclose| < \infty \}.\\
\notag \text{The occurence count of a literal is }oc_f \colon &\mathbb{L} \times \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{N}^0\\
&l, f \xmapsto{\phantom{\mathbb{N}^0}} \mathopen|\{c \in f \mid l \in c\}\mathclose|\\
\notag \text{The reduction set of a variable is }rs_f \colon &\mathbb{V} \times \mathbb{F} \to \{s \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}^0) \mid s \neq \phi \wedge \mathopen|s\mathclose| \leq 2\}\\
&v, f \xmapsto{\phantom{s \subset \mathcal{P}}} \{oc_f(\top, v), oc_f(\bot, v)\}\\
\notag \text{The reduction tuple of a variable is }rt_f \colon &\mathbb{V} \times \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0\\
&v, f \xmapsto{\phantom{\mathbb{N}^0 \times}} \min rs_f(v),\max rs_f(v)\\
\text{flip a tuple if function } fi \colon &(\mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0) \times \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0\\
&(l,r),b \xmapsto{\phantom{\mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0}} \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        r,l & \text{for } b\\
        l,r & \text{for } \neg b
        \end{array}\right.\\
\text{The set of variables in a formula is }\mathbb{V}_f \coloneqq &\{v \in \mathbb{V} \mid \exists_{c \in f}\colon v \in c \}\text{ with }f \in \mathbb{F}.
\end{align}

\section{The Algorithm}
The algorithm is closely related to the Weisfeiler-Leman test of graph isomorphism as described in \cite[p. 2543f]{weisfeiler-leman} in the hypergraph with literals as vertices and clauses as edges. These are the differences:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To preserve information about which literals belong together, the color of the opposite literal is appended to the color of each literal in each iteration.
    \item Graphs are not compared directly, but a normal form for a single graph is computed and then hashed.
    \item The algorithm stops after $h$ iterations, $h$ is fixed.
    \item The label compressor $f$ is not injective, but a hash function. Hash collisions can occur under rare circumstances. The advantage is that it lowers the time complexity for hypergraphs because it avoids comparison based sorting of clauses and that it preserves information about the colors from previous iterations, which is necessary because of the second difference.
\end{enumerate}
The time complexity is $O(i\cdot n\log(n))$ in the implementation, but it could be reduced to $O(i\cdot n)$ with radix sort.
The space complexity is $O(n)$.

\subsection{Implementation details: label compression} \label{label-compression}
$f \circ s_i$ is a commutative combination of $s_i$ entry hashes: clause hashes and the previous color (initially zero). The clause hashes are computed by sorting and then MD5 hashing. The commutative combination is the sum, but with different overflow behavior: instead of wrapping on overflow, a one is carried down. The rationale for adding instead of using XOR is that combining two equal elements leads to a left shift instead of zero, the neutral element. By carrying down on overflow, I make that left shift cyclical so that the most significant bit doesn't get lost. The existence of a neutral element cannot be avoided for commutative hash combinations as proven in \cite{neutral-element}. My sum maps uniformly distributed hashes to a uniformly distributed hash.

\subsection{Half iterations}
To allow more fine-tuning in the trade-off between runtime and precision, I allow half iterations. Weisfeiler-Leman compares the colors only, but I have to insert the colors into the formula anyway at the start of each iteration $> 0$. I call this step literal transformation and the other step variable normalization. Literal transformation sets the colors in relationship with each other and variable normalization hashes that relationship into the variable colors and (hopefully) breaks ties between variables with the same color, so ignoring hash collisions, the false positive rate can't increase not only between iterations, but also between iterations and half iterations. Tie breaks are the driving force that makes an iteration and the following half iteration have potential merit, depending on which hashes are compared to the result. Theoretically, the algorithm could stop once it reaches a fixed point, i.e. no tie gets broken. That would even avoid potential hash collisions in the following iterations. But the effort to keep track of tie breaks is not worth it if the fixed number of iterations is small anyway. $\mathopen|\mathbb{V}_f\mathclose| - 1$ is a theoretical upper bound for the amount of tie breaks and therefore iterations with merit.

\subsection{Pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{literal transformation}
    \KwData{CNF formula $f \in \mathbb{F}$}
    \KwData{color function $c \in \mathbb{V}_f \to \mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0$, initially $rt_f$}
    \KwResult{color normal form $n \coloneqq \sum_{cl \in f}\sum_{s,v \in cl}[fi(c(v),\neg s)]$}
    The implementation is obvious.
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{variable normalization}
    \KwData{CNF formula $f \in \mathbb{F}$}
    \KwData{color normal form $n$, the newest literal transformation result}
    \KwResult{color function $c \in \mathbb{V}_f \to \mathbb{N}^0 \times \mathbb{N}^0$}
    \ForEach{$cl \in f$ and the corresponding $ncl \in n$}{
        sort $ncl$\;
        $h \gets md5(ncl)$\;
        \ForEach{$s,v \in cl$}{
            \tcp{+= uses my special sum as described in \ref{label-compression}}
            \eIf{s}{
                $c(v)$.second += $h$\;
            }{
                $c(v)$.second += $h$\;
            }
        }
    }
    \ForEach{$v \in \mathbb{V}_f$}{
        \If{$c(v)$ is not sorted}{
            flip $c(v)$\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\section*{Evaluation}
I reduced the amount of (true and false) positives from 3740 to 376. % probably incorrect, there were bugs

\section*{Methods and Materials}

Guidelines can be included for standard research article sections, such as this one.

\section*{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
\label{sec:examples}

Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use ref and label commands for cross-references.

\subsection*{Figures and Tables}

Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table~\ref{tab:widgets}, for example. You can upload a figure (JPEG, PNG or PDF) using the project menu. To include it in your document, use the includegraphics command as in the code for Figure~\ref{fig:view} below.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{frog}
\caption{An example image of a frog.}
\label{fig:view}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Candles & 4 \\
Fork handles & ?  
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

\subsection*{Mathematics}

\LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
$$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
      = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

\subsection*{Lists}

You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{enumerate}
\dots or bullet points \dots
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{itemize}
\dots or with words and descriptions \dots
\begin{description}
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Concept] Explanation
\item[Idea] Text
\end{description}

\section*{Acknowledgments}

Additional information can be given in the template, such as to not include funder information in the acknowledgments section.

\bibliography{gbd}

\end{document}


Please extend to a full example, so others can test by just copying the code. We need to see you preamble. If I'm not mistaken, algorithm is just a float, you need more code around the algorithm part.

If I add a suitable simple preamble, the whole algorithm appears.

I added an Overleaf link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/bvmttmqgbhds#90beba

Note that links rot over time making your question unusable. Please copy the code here

Ok, I pasted it.

Your example is not working because of using a class, that is not available on CTAN and therefore not in TeXLive or MiKTeX. Can you show an example using a standard class, e.g., article, or another free class available from CTAN?

can you not reproduce your problem using article class? If the problem requires olplainarticle.cls then you should provide  it, as that would  mean the problem is in code you have not shown, so makes an answer impossible.

Similarly your example now includes \bibliography{gbd} if that file is required to see the problem (which seems highly unlikely) then supply the file, otherwise please remove it (and all the other unrelated text) from the test file.

I just found out that the algorithm did appear, but the second for loop made it too big, so it got moved to the next page. I didn't expect this because a new section starts at the same page. How can I keep it in its subsection?

It's \begin{algorithm}[H], my problem is resolved.

The algorithm was in the wrong section on another page and not absent, so \begin{algorithm}[H] was the solution to my problem.
